# MongoDB driver pagination

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

Currently I am able to return all my products from the collection.
I however want to be able to return products that come after a specific product ID (which would be the last one on the client side so they could load more)

**Current way (return all)**

```
query := bson.M{}

var product ReturnedProdcut
    var products []ReturnedProduct
    cur, err := mg.Db.Collection("products").Find(c.Request().Context(), query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for cur.Next(c.Request().Context()) {
        err := cur.Decode(&product)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        products = append(products, product)

    }

    // return products list in JSON format
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, products)
```

**New Way Attempt(return based on page)**

```
afterID := c.QueryParam("afterID")
if afterID == "" {
   // get from start of collection based on latest date
}
// get 10 products after this ID, if no ID then get from start

query := bson.M{}

var product ReturnedProduct
    var products []Returnedproduct
    //.find(afterId).limit(10) - something like this?
    
    cur, err := mg.Db.Collection("products").Find(c.Request().Context(), query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for cur.Next(c.Request().Context()) {
        err := cur.Decode(&product)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        products = append(products, product)

    }

    // return products list in JSON format
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, products)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may construct a query where `_id` is greater than `afterID`, in which case you should also specify sorting by `_id`. For sorting and for setting a limit, you may use [`options.FindOptions`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.4/mongo/options#FindOptions).

You also should use [`Cursor.All()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.All) to decode all results and not one-by-one.

This is how it could look like:

```
query := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$gt": afterID}}
opts := options.Find().
    SetSort(bson.M{"_id": 1}).
    SetLimit(10)
    
ctx := c.Request().Context()

curs, err := mg.Db.Collection("products").Find(ctx, query, opts)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

var products []Returnedproduct
if err = curs.All(ctx, &products); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, products)
```

Comment: My ids are primitive.ObjectID so they cannot be sorted by numerical I assume?

Comment: @Henry ObjectID's are ordered, they can be sorted, which roughly is equivalent with the time order (to the second precision).

Answer (score 2):

The official [MongoDB Go driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go) also has a `*FindOptions` optional parameter you could also explore.

```
 pageOptions := options.Find()
 pageOptions.SetSkip(int64(page)) //0-i
 pageOptions.SetLimit(int64(limit)) // number of records to return

 cur, err := userCollection.Find(c.Request().Context(), bson.D{{}}, pageOptions)
 if err != nil {
    // handle error
 }

 defer cur.Close(ctx)
 var products []Returnedproduct
 for cur.Next(c.Request().Context()) {
    var product Returnedproduct
    if err := cur.Decode(&product); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    products = append(products, &product)
 }

 if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
    // handle error
 }
```

Comment: I think you'll want to multiply `page` by `limit` to get the right number to skip, otherwise each page basically increments by one.